# using pinentry-tty in a bash script (like read)

Tags: bash

Is there a way to use pinentry-tty directly in a bashscript? E.G. as a more secure replacement for 'read'. I was thinking of something like this:

```
local pass=$(pinentry-tty);
```

This allows me to enter several lines, but nothing gets saved to the variable.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful for some other cases. But here, I'm looking for a way to use it outside of gpg.

Answer (score 3):

The different `pinentry` implementations cannot easily be called the way you wanted to use it. It follows a simple protocol, which also enables several possibilities to configure prompts and print error messages. An example session, with `GETPIN` being the command issued on `STDIN` and `foo` being the passphrase the user entered, returned with other status messages on `STDOUT`:

```
$ pinentry
OK Pleased to meet you
GETPIN
D foo
OK
```

The full documentation is included in [pinentry's source tarball](https://www.gnupg.org/download/index.html#pinentry), but [also available online](http://info2html.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/info2html-demo/info2html?%28pinentry%29Protocol).

Answer (score 1):

While this won't work with all pinentry implementations you can try invoking it as follows:

```sh
password=$(echo -e "SETPROMPT Please enter your password:\nGETPIN\n" | \
           pinentry | \
           sed -nr '0,/^D (.+)/s//\1/p')
```

On my Arch machine this works for `pinentry-gnome3`, `pinentry-gtk-2` and `pinentry-qt` - but not with `pinentry-curses` or `pinentry-tty`

Answer (score 1):

The two previous solutions work only for GUI based pinentry frontends. The `-T`/`--ttyname` option should be used for entering pin in terminal (pinentry-curses).

```bash
TTY=$(tty)
password=$(echo "GETPIN" | pinentry -T $TTY | grep D)
password=${password#D }
```