# Update the content of an encrypted file using gpg2 and bash scripting

Tags: bash, encryption, gnupg

Say there's an encrypted file file.txt

In order to update its content the file must be decrypted first, then run through the desired processing and afterwards it must be encrypted again.

(1) What would be the most straight forward way to do so in bash scripting using gpg2? The operation should request the user only once for a password to decrypt. It should use the same password for the final encryption afterwards.

Here is a most likely extremely unsecure, but working example of what I try to archieve:

```
function update-encrypted-file() {
   read pass_tmp;
   local pass=$pass_tmp;
   unset pass_tmp;

   local file="file.txt";
   local tmp_result=$(cat $file | gpg2 --batch --passphrase $pass | update);
   echo $tmp_result | gpg2 -c --batch --passphrase $pass > $file;
}
```

whereas update might be sth. like this: `alias update="tr -d X"` (delete all X's)

(2) What exactly could make the above example insecure? I guess using `read` itself is a no-go, but it would be interesting to see why. Not having the variable set locally causes the password to be inside the global space for some short time. Could that possibly be fetched? I could not figure out how to use pinentry-tty in this case (see [this post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410670/using-pinentry-tty-in-a-bash-script-like-read)

(3) Apart from that, the gpg2 documentation remarks regarding the `--passphrase` option: "Obviously, this is of very questionable security on a multi-user system. Don't use this  option  if  you can  avoid  it."
Is this only the case when manually used inside a terminal, since the commands are logged? Or would there also be concerns when using e.g. inside a function with the password having saved in only this function scope.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not answering your individual questions directly, but have a slight discussion of password management and GnuPG, but for the third question: the command line of *all* processes from *all* users running on the machine are available to *anybody*. To confirm, just run a simple `ps ax` as an unprivileged user. Never pass secrets as parameters!

Obviously, the most secure option will be to *never get hold of the passphrase at all*. If you don't have it, you can't mess with it. With GnuPG 2.1, this was even applied to the actual GnuPG binary (`gpg`/`gpg2`): The most critical secret key operations (involving handling the passphrase) are performed by the small `gpg-agent` (thus having smaller attack surface), the rather large and complicated GnuPG binary neither gets direcct access to the key nor the passphrase.

This is also what I'd go for: instead of handling the passphrase, rely on `gpg-agent` doing so instead. It is available (and since GnuPG 2.1, also required) anyway. If configured properly (and this is the default), `gpg-agent` will cache the passphrase for a while. If the user configured something else, he decided he does not want cached passphrases, which you also should respect with your application.

As soon as required, the `gpg-agent` will query the user for the passphrase through the configured method -- if you're running a graphical user interface, this will likely be a window popping up.

If you mess with the GnuPG configuration (for example, your own configuration files, starting your own `gpg-agent`, ...), it's your job of course to take care of this. To start your own instance of `gpg-agent` to have full control over caching and other options, take advantage of the `--options`, `--homedir` and `--no-use-standard-socket` as required by your individual use case.

---

Finally, you're storing an intermediate result of the contents, which you `echo`:

```
local tmp_result=$(cat $file | gpg2 --batch --passphrase $pass | update);
echo $tmp_result | gpg2 -c --batch --passphrase $pass > $file;
```

Don't do this for the same reasons discussed for passphrases! Instead,  directly pipe the result into the encryption process (and there is no need for `cat` here):

```
< $file gpg2 --batch --passphrase $pass | update | gpg2 -c --batch --passphrase $pass > $file;
```

Comment: are you sure the last example should work? I end up having an empty file instead of an updated one. Isn't that due to the problem of having stdin and stdout to the same file? e.g. like: < file tr -d x > file

Comment: Indeed, didn't think about that. But better write to a temporary file and then move back instead of storing the content in a variable. You will be running into all sorts of (size) limitations, and better never store the unencrypted version at all.

Comment: and for future reference, `echo $unquotedVar` is a shell anti-pattern, certain to cause trouble when a `\r,\n` or many Ctrl-Chars are in that value. In general, dbl-quote all of  your variables! Agree that they're not needed here, except for `"$file", "$pass"`. Good luck to all.